# I am not able to access windows after installation of ubuntu by dual boot i have tried everything boot repair please help

Tags: boot, dual-boot, xubuntu

Help me with the error please. Here is the link for boot repair report.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mPXdKQmGsY

Comment: In UEFI mode, you can always boot Windows by invoking the EFI menu, some function key at power-up to allow you to select boot device/OS -- select Windows, and that skips grub entirely.

Comment: Did you create a second ESP on your NVMe drive? You can only have one per drive. Your p1 parttition is labeled "ESP", but Ubuntu is booting from p5. Move boot flag back to p1 with gparted & using Boot-Repair totally reinstall grub, so it uses p1 as ESP. Not sure then if Windows UEFI boot files are still in p1 or not. Repair does not show all details on NVMe drives. If not you may need to reinstall Windows boot files.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `sudo update-grub`? Your Windows isn't showing in your grub.cfg file:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Also, type this if that didn't work:
in terminal>

```
sudo grub-mkconfig
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thats not the grub.cfg file, but for some reason, it is not shown in the boot-repair report (old one?).  The report's "95 Windows not detected by os-prober on nvme0n1p3" probably means update-grub will fail to find Windows (again).

Comment: Oh wow. Yup, I'm going to sleep. I haven't slept in nearly 30 hours. You are right on both parts, especially the os-prober; I'll check in on this later, curious what the underlying issue is. Ouch! I only use Windows for gaming, but that still has to hurt. I'm rarely in Windows, but it better be there when I call on it.